# How to use php and java apis on the same proxy server to interact with a remote application server through webservices

Tags: php, tomcat, proxy, server, webserver

I am having one proxy webserver and I was only using php APIs that interact with a remote application server. Now I want to use also java APIs and all I know is to install tomacat but I don't know how to configure my server to listen for php and java requests.
I will appreciate your tips. Thanks

Comment: Abit confused as to what you mean by proxy, something like [nginx as a reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) could do this and just upstream to the different listening services, servers or ports

Comment: To describe the question: My application server is behind a webserver and a webserver is used as proxy to the application server. This is configured in virtual host. There are php APIs on my webserver that interact with my application on the application server. Now I also want to use java APIs in parallel with php APIs on the webserver. The domain will be the same. Hope I am clear now. Let me know if I need to explain more.

Comment: To add that I use apache webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this great series about configuring and setting up a modern LEMP for PHP.

https://serversforhackers.com/s/lemp-stack-php-71

It will guide you on how to setup and configure your server in a secure manner which will also co-incide with Tomcat. Just remember to listen on different ports for Tomcat and PHP/nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that it's easy. Either I call files using the same same domain http://thesamedomain:8080 since my tomcat is listenning on port 8080. Or I use another domain and create vhost like this:

ServerName predevjava.mcash.rw 
ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests off 
ProxyPass / http://anotherdomain:8080/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://anotherdomain:8080/

Remember tomcat files are by default located in /opt/tomcat/webapps

So any time you call http://samedomain it fetches php files (port 80 by default) and any time you http://samedomain:8080 it fetches java files in tomcat.

Or simply you call http://anotherdomain and it calls java files. As simple as that.